Production SQLX and PgBouncer's Prepared Statement Issue
In production i got multiple SQL Servers where i have to use connection pooler like pgbouncer and i got high traffic so i am thinking of transaction mode.
In pgbouncer i changed the number of allowed prepared statements as well to 1000:
pool_mode = transaction

;; Number of prepared statements to cache on a server connection (zero value
;; disables support of prepared statements).
max_prepared_statements = 1000

Now Pgbouncer says we got support for prepared statements from version 1.21 and i got currently 1.22.
However, it flat out fails to run even, when i use session mode then it works perfect but CPU usage goes high and latency as well from 47ms to 240ms. Whole infrastructure is at local server.
error returned from database: prepared statement "sqlx_s_1" does not exist

Here is my connection pool config for Postgresql under main.rs
let pool = match PgPoolOptions::new()
        .max_connections(10) // Set the maximum number of connections in the pool.
        .connect(&config.database_url)
        .await

In sqlx documentation i found raw_sql, i haven't tried it yet as then i am looking at significant code change because bind is not supported and then you build the query string on your own.
Here is my sample query:
user = sqlx::query_as!(
                User,
                r#"SELECT id, name, username, email, password, verified, created_at, updated_at FROM users WHERE id = $1"#,
                user_id
            ).fetch_optional(&self.pool).await?;

